# How to locate HP Windows 8.1 acceleration settings for Flash Player Settings if its not there?

Tags: windows-8.1, flash-player

Well basically, when I right click onto the video and click onto the settings. The Adobe Flash Player settings does not display the acceleration setting. I have update to the latest version (Windows 8.1 64-bit machine), my shockwave is enabled and the ActiveX Filtering is disabled. Please tell me how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Why can't you update your flash installation?  What browser are we talking about?

Comment: I can update it and it's installed. The browser I am using is Internet Explorer.

Comment: IE11 has Flash built in.  What version of flash is detected.

Comment: IE11 is not applicable with my windows 8.1

Comment: It has to be.  You can't have Windows 8.1 installed without IE11 being installed.  **Go double check**  I can guarantee that your running IE11, doesn't really matter, IE10 also has it built-in.  **Anything before IE11 does not support 8.1**